# Best way to classify text based on a set of seed/keywords

Tags: classification, text-mining, semi-supervised-learning

This question was asked six years ago but figured it was worth an update.

I'm attempting to filter news data based on a set of keywords. I think the ideal process for this would be some form of:

- Input keyword list ->
- Identify additional words that commonly occur with this seed list in vector space. ->
- Tag all articles that relate to these set of key words (e.g. topics) and assign a relevancy score.

So far the best option seems to be some form of topic modeling such as the following https://ryanjgallagher.github.io/code/corex/overview. However, I am not loving the result I am getting with this package and wondering if others had a suggested workflow?